# How can I test if a variable equals any of several options?

Tags: python

I am helping a friend with some code for a school helping bot, but I've run into a problem. On the last line, where it says: if helpselect == ('*****'): , I am trying to add multiple conditions in one line of code so that the specific line of code activates when they type math or math. HELP

```
import time 
print('Hello, my name is CareBot and I am here to help!') 
time.sleep(3) 
name = input('Please input your name: ') 
print('Nice to meet you, %s. I am a bot that can lead you to resources to help out with school subjects!' % name) 
time.sleep(2) 
print('Now, what subject can I help you with?') 
helpselect = input('Please input a subject: ') 
if helpselect == ('*****'):
```

Comment: You can create a set of strings and use `in` operator to check if `helpselect` is a part of that set.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: try `if helpselect == value or helpselect == other_value:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
if helpselect in {"math", "english"}:
    print("You selected math or english")
```

Something like that? (You said "when they type math or math", which is redundant.)

Comment: I meant like, math (lowercase M) or Math (Capital M). But yes, it worked. THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: @GrahamLewis If you want to do case-insensitive comparison, you can convert `helpselect` to lowercase or uppercase and then compare against `math` or `MATH` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to check if the person typed a certain subject then I might create a set of strings. When you check if something is in a set of strings you are checking whether or not the word you typed is one of the words in the set of strings.

```
setofstrings = ["math", "english", "science"]

if helpselect in setofstrings:
```

or perhaps you want to do this.

```
if helpselect == "math" or helpselect == "english":
```

If you're trying to check if there are any math symbols in a line of code.
What I would do is create a string called mathsymbols.

```
mathsymbols = "+-*/"
```

Then check and see if the input contains any math symbols by doing this line of code. This checks if what you typed any individual character in the string mathsymbols.

```
if helpselect in mathsymbols:
```

I would want learn sets, strings, the "in" operator, "and", "or", etc.